# Why does the function `GenSA` not honor lower bounds for components?

Tags: r, parameters, simulated-annealing

Quoting [the official documentation of the `GenSA` function from the `GenSA` package from CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GenSA/GenSA.pdf):

> ### Usage
>
> ```
> GenSA(par, fn, lower, upper, control=list(), ...)
> ```
>
> ### Arguments
>
> - `par` Vector. Initial values for the components to be
>     optimized.  Default is `NULL`, in which case, default values will be
>     generated automatically.
> - `fn` A function to be minimized, with first
>     argument the vector of parameters over which minimization is to take
>     place. It should return a scalar result.
> - `lower` Vector with length of `par`.
>     Lower bounds for components.
> - `upper` Vector with length of `par`. Upper
>     bounds for components.

Very well. So, if I undestand correctly, the arguments passed to `fn` should never be lower or higher than the bounds I specify in `lower` and `higher`.

This seems not to be the case:

```
library(GenSA)

GenSA(c(1.0/90, 1.0, 0.02), function(args){
  arg1 = args[1]; arg2 = args[2]; arg3 = args[3]
  print(args)
  if(arg2 <= 0) stop("WTF")
  0
}, lower=c(0, 1.0, 0), upper=c(Inf, Inf, 0.4))
```

The results of running this code are unforgiving:

```
[1] 0.01111111 1.00000000 0.02000000
[1] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.2891973
Error in fn(par, ...) : WTF
Calls: GenSA -> <Anonymous> -> fn
Execution halted
```

Why did `GenSA` call my function with the second component equaling `0.0`? I thought I was clear when I said: `lower=c(0, 1.0, 0)`!

Am I misunderstanding something? What is my mistake? How can this be forced to work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Culprit:

```
upper=c(Inf, Inf, 0.4)
```

Remove the `Inf`s and set this to `upper=c(100, 100, 0.4)` and lower bounds finally seem to be honored.

Don't know why.